# se puede imprimir componentes por evento en react js?

Tags: reactjs

necesito que cada vez que pulse un botón me imprima mi componente cada uno con un id para pasar valores en un futuro, es posible?

ya intente con la documentación de manejo de eventos pero solo me da mensajes por consola

Comment: ¿Y si guardas en el state, en una variable "numCompontents" por ejemplo, que se vaya incrementando, y en el render haces que por cada numComponentes cree tu componente? Un `for` de toda la vida.

Comment: yo pensaba en el constructor, cada ves que se llame al componente incrementar una variable global, pero el problema radica en, como hacer que el botón me imprima mi componente?

Comment: intente con <button={<component/>}>componenteNuevo<button/>

Comment: Una página solo llama el constructor una vez. Si quieres añadir más componentes en la misma página, el `state` debe ser modificado, o que la misma página reciba nuevas props. Si modificas el `state`, y un valor en el render depende de este mismo, volverá a renderizarse el render. Es dentro del render, en el que tendrás que hacer un bucle para que te renderice tu componente dependiendo de alguna variable del state.

Comment: modificando el state modifico ese mismo componente no?, lo que yo necesito es tener 3 o 6 componentes iguales en la misma pagina, por ejemplo tengo un componente que imprime hola quiero que al dar al boton 5 veces me imprima 5 veces hola, no modificar el hola

Answer (score 0):

Según el ejemplo que me has pasado.

Inicializa el state con un atributo "numHolas: 1" (desconozco si usas hooks, usaré la forma tradicional)

Constructor inicializas el state

```
this.state = {
    numHolas: 1
}
```

Ten tu función que mostrará el número de holas, aunque aquí puedes llamar a cualquier componente propio tuyo, siempre que los englobes dentro de un contenedor.

```
renderHolas () {
    let string = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.numHolas; i++) {
        string = string + 'hola'
    }
    return string
}
```

Y en el render

```
render () {
    return {
        <TuBotón onClick={() => { this.setState{
                numHolas: this.state.numHolas++
            }
        }} />
        {this.renderHolas()}
    }
}
```

Como numHolas del state a sido modificado, al renderizarse de nuevo el render, se volverá a llamar a la función `renderHolas()`